# Blazor WebAssembly："Prerender" just only work for home page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a "Blazor WebAssembly" project to test "Prerender" according to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly

Here is my source code:

https://temp-file.org/4w714tuZB0hBGN2/file

But I found the problem after starting up the proejct. The home page was transferred OK.Then when I click the "Counter" on the left hand site of the home page, the page transfer is OK too. But then when I click the refresh button on the browser will return the 404 error:

> http://localhost:5287/counter

> HTTP ERROR 404

This showed that it could not visit the "/counter" and other pages directly
except the home page.

How can I fix the problem to let the "Prerender" work for all page？

Thank you in advance for any help！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your project, in `Program.cs` of Server project, it should be

```
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

not

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("/_Host");
```

Also, in `_Host.cshtml`, the official documentation states to add `@namespace {APP NAMESPACE}.Client`, not `@using {APP NAMESPACE}.Client`. Although there will be no impact, I suggest you follow the documentation.

Of course, when refreshing the `FetchData` page, this error occurs:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http' on type 'BlazorAppTest.Client.Pages.FetchData'. There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.
```

According to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46737), Microsoft may be preparing to fix it in `.Net 8.0`.